# Why does the browser close automatically after the tasks are executed when I'm using selenium with Ruby?

Tags: ruby, selenium, selenium-webdriver, cucumber, deprecation-warning

I'm starting to learn Ruby along with selenium and cucumber:
I'm running on ubuntu and using Firefox as a browser
Ubuntu: 
Description:    Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS
Release:    18.04

Firefox version: 72.0.1
selenium-webdriver version : 3.142.7
Ruby version: 2.5.1p57

I've started with a small simple test:

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'selenium-webdriver'

driver = Selenium::WebDriver.for :firefox
driver.get "http://google.com"
element = driver.find_element(name: "q")
element.send_keys "Cheese!"
element.submit
```

After "Cheese" is submitted to the search bar, the browser closes immediatly.

I want to leave it open so what can I do ? I have found this suggested solution :

```
caps = Selenium::WebDriver::Remote::Capabilities.firefox(:firefox_options => {detach: true})
driver = Selenium::WebDriver.for :firefox, desired_capabilities: caps
```

But when I add it to my code I get this deprecation warning:

```
2020-01-23 10:12:35 WARN Selenium [DEPRECATION] :firefox_options capabilitiy is deprecated. Use Selenium::WebDriver::Firefox::Options instead.
```

I tried using Options but haven't succeeded because I must've done it wrong. Here's what I have done

```
opt = Selenium::WebDriver::Firefox::Options.new
opt.add_preference("detach","true")
caps = Selenium::WebDriver::Remote::Capabilities.firefox(opt)
driver = Selenium::WebDriver.for :firefox, desired_capabilities: caps
```

I get the following error:

```
`firefox': undefined method `key?' for #<Selenium::WebDriver::Firefox::Options:0x000055e1a6c58158> (NoMethodError)
```

Comment: The line `driver.get "http://google.` is missing the closing quote. I assume this is not the case in your code. Could you add the missing code?

Comment: Oh, my bad. It's just  "http://google.com"

Comment: *"I tried using Options but haven't succeeded because I must've done it wrong."* Could you also add your current attempt to use `Selenium::WebDriver::Firefox::Options`? Instead of simply finding a solution it's often better to know what went wrong and why. Furthermore people reading your question are interested in what your current attempt was. You might also want to add what the output of your attempt was. Did it produce an error? Did you not get the output you wanted?

Comment: Alright, I will do it now. Thank you for the advice.

Answer (score 0):

I am pretty sure that it wouldn't happen for firefox, And I took your code and executed and it's not closing. It happens only for Chrome. If you are using Chrome, then write the following code.

```
caps = Selenium::WebDriver::Remote::Capabilities.chrome("goog:chromeOptions" => {detach: true})
driver = Selenium::WebDriver.for :chrome, desired_capabilities: caps
```

Comment: But it is happening and on Firefox. And I stated which version of Firefox and all.

Comment: I am using next version 72.0.2. Can you upgrade and check it?

Comment: I just did, the problem persists.

Answer (score 0):

Check your IDE or packages you're using. Many of them auto-build in close scripts. This is the likely issue you're running into.

If you run just the ruby script from your terminal it won't close. Try dieting things down. Items like Capybara / Cucumber can have hooks registered that may be affecting this.

Comment: The thing is i'm not using any IDE. I'm just executing everything via command line.